# Z87 Chipset MB and Haswell Refresh processor refuses to work (Asus Z87M-PLUS + Core i5-4590)

Tags: haswell

I have two motherboards and two processors:
1. Asus Z87M-PLUS motherboard with latest BIOS (1106, updated via Asus EZ Flash menu in BIOS). It works perfectly with Intel Core i3-4130.
2. ASUS H81I-PLUS with Core i5-4590. This pair works well too.

But when I install i5-4590 into Z87M-Plus this combination does not work (CPU fan is spinning but monitor stays black and I hear no POST beep).

I tried to clear CMOS - no effect. All other devices (e.g. videocard or hdd) is disconnected. RAM = 2x4 DDR3 Kingmax Nano (2200MHz).

Has anyone faced with a similar problem? How can I force this CPU+MB combination to work?

Comment: you have confirmed the non-working CPU actually does work in another system?

Comment: Yes, the I5-4590 CPU works with Asus H81I motherboard.

Comment: The non-working CPU is listed as being supported by the Z87?  Have you contacted ASUS for assistance?

Comment: The non-working CPU is listed as being supported by Asus Z87M-PLUS motherboard since BIOS ver 1003. No, I haven't contact ASUS support yet.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally got a solution after getting an email to Asus Support.

The Haswell Refresh BIOS update consists from two parts: the bios update and intel ME microcode update. The last one can only be installed from Windows using "BIOS updater for New 4th Gen Intel Core Processors" (you can find it at suport.asus.com).
And since my Z87 motherboard was not certified to work with Windows 10, I couldn't flash me microcode update from Windows 10.

So I've installed Windows 7 and Intel ME Driver. After that I was able to successfully update the bios and me microsode of my motherboard using "BIOS updater for New 4th Gen Intel Core Processors".

Comment: Hey there. I have done all the same, but the problem still persists. Have you updated the microcode apart from the BIOS?

Comment: Yes! You must update both microcode and bios. I suppose you know how to update bios. And I wrote about updating microcode in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work in my case (however i had Win 8.1 - maybe that was the problem?). Bought a new motherboard and worked flawlessly.